# Creating a Cyrillic font with OSX Glyphs.app fails when made web safe

Tags: fonts, font-face, web-fonts

I have a full Latin alphanumeric font made and am attempting to add Cyrillic characters to the mix.

I am using OSX Glyphs.app.

I am able to make the Cyrillic characters and export the font as an .OTF. I can boot in to Illustrator or any other application and access the Cyrillic characters without fault.

However, when I try to convert my font to web safe fonts via http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator, All characters other than my Cyrillic characters work properly. For example: I have tried using `И`, `&#1048;`, and `&#x418;` to no effect.

[image: Latin N vs Cyrillic Ii]

On the left is Cyrillic Ii and on the right is Latin N. The font has been saved with Cyrillic Ii merely being a mirrored N. All of this works fine in apps, but fails on web.

Can anyone think of a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create webfonts with Cyrillic glyphs with @font-face generator you should select `Expert...` setting, find `Subsetting:` group, switch it to `Custom Subsetting...` and select `Cyrillic` checkbox.

Comment: Excellent. I had no idea those options existed. Guess I should have poked around more. Thanks!